# Phonegap Build android - error "Adding the android platform" ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova, command-line

Helo, 
I am currently trying to build the base phonegapp android app that's automatically created, so I navigated to the directory... but when I use the command

```
phonegap build android
```

I just get this random error, as shown in the attatched picture. 
[image]

**Extra info**

I am currently on Windows 8, and am completely new to making apps, and am new to the command line as well. Not very familiar with this stuff...

What I'm trying to do would be called 'compiling', right?

Comment: Are you accessing any file form your device in your code?

Comment: @SiddharthVyas what do you mean? I am using the basic 'automatically created' project file, and all of the automatically generated content - so I'm pretty sure it's not the app I'm trying to compile that's causing the problem.

Comment: Have you installed all that's listed in the phonegap doc "Android platform guide" add added everything to the path? Ant, java JDK, android sdk+api19 check others question in SO there are plenty of other questions like yours.

Comment: user --verbose to see complete error use "phonegap build android --verbose"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, I had the same problem yesterday - but with a little help of a colleague I got it!

### Step by step tutorial (for Windows)

1. Install [node js](http://nodejs.org/)
2. Install phonegap using command line: `npm install -g phonegap`
3. Install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
4. Launch Android SDK Manager and install Android 4.4.2 (API19)

   - Because latest phonegap/cordova version requires this
   - Documentation for Android SDK and SDK Platform should be enough
   - Also update already existing packages
5. Create an environment variable called `ANDROID_HOME` which points to destination of Android SDK. *e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk*
6. Download [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) and extract the archive somewhere
7. Create an environment variable called `ANT_HOME` which points to destination where you have extracted Ant
8. Install [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) (Java Development Kit) for your System. Before you are able to download, you have to accept the licence
9. Create an environment variable called `JAVA_HOME` which points to destination of JDK
10. If you want to add plugins via phonegap automatically you should also install [GIT](http://git-scm.com/downloads).
11. Last but not least you need to add the following directories to `PATH` environment variable:

    - `%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
    - Each folder is separated by a semicolon

Setting environment variables will take effect just for new command line windows. So you should reopen it, after the whole process.

Easy, isn't it? ;-)

Now you can use `phonegap build android` after you've created a new phonegap project. If you have your smartphone plugged via USB and installed the USB drivers, and activated the USB Debugging on smartphone, you may use

`phonegap run android`

And the ready build APK will be transfered and executed on your smartphone. Perfect for testing.

If you want to create a final release APK, go to 
`YOURPROJECT\platforms\android\ant-build`
and enter `ant release`.
You'll find the final APKs in `YOURPROJECT\platforms\android\bin`.

They are unsigned, here is a [Noob guide to signing an APK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1231561).

I have tested a Barcode Scanner example, and it works seamlessly.

Have fun!

Comment: Plus one even I still have problem. But that explanation's guides closer. I even can not run the desktop phone-gap at the beginning with code 1. But still can create project using cordova CLI.

Answer (score 2):

also check `android` in `cmd`, if it says: `'xcopy' was not recognized`.

then add to your path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Armin's guide is perfect. But if you still fail you can do this. 
Phonegap platform files stay in C:\Users[username].cordova\lib folder. Go there and remove android/ios/bb... driectory.

For best result run this command:

```
    npm cache clear
```

After that try again, clean platfrom files will be download and build your project.